# Asymptotic lower bound for the maximum of $n$ iid binomial random variables

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{Binom}(n,p)$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$ (assume that $p=o(\log n/n)$). Prove that
$$
\Pr(\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i \geq k^*) \rightarrow 1 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty,
$$
where $k=\frac{\log n}{\log(\log n/(np))}$.

---

I tried the following approach but failed to get anything useful:
$$
\Pr(\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i < k^*) = (\Pr(X_1 < k^*))^n,
$$
where
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X_1 < k^*)=\sum_{j=0}^{k^*-1} \binom{n}{j} \cdot p^j \cdot (1-p)^{n-j}<\sum_{j=0}^{k^*-1} n^j \cdot p^j \cdot (1-p)^{n-j}=(1-p)^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k^*-1} \left(\frac{np}{1-p}\right)^j=...
\end{align*}